# Generating COBOL code with C#

Tags: c#, cobol

I have to generate COBOL code with C# but I haven't got suitable ideas how I could tackle this problem.

The only idea which I have was to generate the COBOL code as plain text but I think this isn't really efficient.

Are there any other/better ways? Could anyone provide an approach for me?
I would be also glad to hear about the smallest tips.

For your information: The data, which I need for the COBOL code I get from a PDF file. Unfortunately I am not able to use Cobol.NET.

The main goal is that a user is able to open a PDF file in the C# program. This PDF file is an empty form where the user have to place several kind of data on it. After editing this form the user must press a button 'run'. The 'run'-button trigger an event which translate the data into COBOL code. Now the COBOL code should contain the data types, values and coordinates of the used fields (data). The coordinates identify the place where the fields should printed on the formular.

Comment: Write a compiler that compiles C# code into COBOL.

Comment: ^LOL. You do not provide much information as to WHY you are generating the cobol code and not just writing it?

Comment: Maybe use [T4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit)?

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to convert my C# code into Cobol code. I have to write a C# program that generates Cobol code.

Comment: @PatrickVogt Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: @PatrickVogt to do what?  That's like asking "How long is a piece of string?"

Comment: At the moment T4 sounds really good. Thank you.

Comment: "I have to write a C# program that generates COBOL".  Not a problem that most people start their day with.  What's the motivation?  (In the worst case, you can simply use a bunch of print string calls to meet the original objective).

Comment: Are you really wanting to generate COBOL code - something that then needs to be compiled, or, are you trying to generate a data file that a COBOL program can read. Maybe a file with binary data in it representing what COBOL might recognize as a COMP-3 or something like that? If this is your requirement please give the COBOL record defiinitions you need to mimic and the target operating system.

Comment: I really wanting to generate COBOL code. This code will be deliver to a Host-Computer (z/OS) where the code will be compiled.

Comment: It is really unclear to me what you are trying to do. Can you show an example of what you have in the .PDF and what you want to get as the output from processing that? What do you mean by text not being efficient?

Comment: It perfectly clear to me that the OP wants to generate COBOL code using a C# program. I do not see whats unclear about the question. He did not explain the reason behind it but COBOL is verbose, tedious and repetitive so any automation is useful.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Visual Studio I'd suggest looking into [T4 Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). They allow you to specify the format of your output as it will appear and write C# to manipulate that output.

Comment: I have done this using T4 templates and it worked quite well ( Not as well as Java/Freemarker but OK). You need quite a bit of fiddling with the T4 properties as the default it to generate inline code in the program you are editing which is not what you want.